# From 32 + 32 bit to double

Tags: java, endianness, bytebuffer

for some reason I need to retrieve a double value from two 32 bit. Let me explain:
On the server side they send a double value formatted like this:

```
  // C/C++ = SERVER 
  double big;
  big = 12345.67890;
  unsigned int *pi = (unsigned int *)&big;

  unsigned int x = pi[0];
  unsigned int y = pi[1];
```

they send from the server to the client a double formatted with two unsigned int (x and y, 32 bit each in my case).
On the client side (JAVA) I need to build again the double value from the two unsigned integers received. I tried this without success:

```
// double double64 = buffer2.getDouble();
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(16);
buffer.putLong(my_int_x);
buffer.putLong(my_int_y);
buffer.flip();
double double64 = buffer.getDouble();
```

maybe because I'm receiving a 32 bit integer and I use "putLong"?

Comment: A long is 64 bits in Java. Is there something like putInt you could use instead?

Comment: @Jorge_B: I used "like this" not by case ... I've just sent a PoC code to try to explain my problem in few lines of code. 
And just fyi the server is multiplatform and servers something like half million request every day ... but thanks for your advice ;-)

Comment: Maybe not a fortunate comment at all, let me make it more constructive: I see a portability threat in assuming things about the size of a type in C, since every data type has not had the same size historically in all architectures and implementations of C.  However, if it is not exactly your production code, then there is no threat

Comment: As an example of this, item 4 in http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/ warns about this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To convert two ints (containing double data) into a double, you don't need a temporary buffer. You can do this:

```
long doubleBits = my_int_x & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
doubleBits <<= 32;
doubleBits |= my_int_y & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
double myDouble = Double.longBitsToDouble(doubleBits);
```

However, check how you are reading my_int_x and my_int_y in your Java program. Maybe you can get a double directly at that moment (ideally, you should).

Comment: I don't see any endianness problem here ... double type representation is standard (IEEE 754) and on the java side there is not endianness involved, we just copy two buffer.